# ASIHTTP - Leave the view and get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I'm running an http request with my view controller as the delegate using ASIHTTP, if the user leaves the view controller before the request is done, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the ASIHTTP code that is doing an if ( delegate ... )

Is there something I have to do in my view controller dealloc? I want to simply drop the request if the user leaves.

Comment: This is usually a problem with your code. Post some and we'll try to decipher the problem.

Comment: If there is a crash, there is a backtrace or crash log. post it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common reason for problems like this is an ASIHTTPRequest object that is still active and where its delegate field points at an object that is now destroyed. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS will then happen when ASIHTTPRequest tries to tell the delegate the request has finished and so on.

Your dealloc method *for the object that is the asihttprequest delegate* should have:

```
request.delegate = nil;
[request cancel]
[request release]
```

If you have only one request active at a time, you must have this same code anywhere you start a new request, to ensure that any previous request is correctly cancelled.

If you have more than one request active, you will need to keep track of all of them, and cancel and nil the delegate of all of them.

For reference, I've been using ASIHTTPRequest for ~18 months, and have contributed back a number of fixes for difficult race conditions related to cancelling requests.

Comment: You don't have to release the request.

Comment: @peterp Not sure I understand: If you don't release the request you'll get a memory leak. (And you have to retain the request as otherwise you have no way to guarantee it'll still be around for you to cancel in your dealloc method.)

Comment: @josephH You don't have to retain it because you don't have to guarantee that it should be around in your dealloc method. If it isn't around in your dealloc method then you don't have a problem anymore.

Comment: @peterp The problem is you need to make sure it definitely will not call your delegate after dealloc has been called, as if it does that will cause a crash. The simplest way to guarantee that is to retain the request and cancel (and release) it in dealloc. If you don't retain it, the cancel call may call an already deallocated object (if the request has already completed), which would then result in a crash. If you have a better way, please do post your own answer!

Comment: I wasn't even keeping the request around. I had never considered the user could enter the view and leave before the request finished.